# I'm running nginx with fastcgi, is that all I need to serve python apps also?

Tags: python

I'm running ubuntu with nginx with fastcgi, is that all I need to serve python apps also?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably also need [flup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup) to bridge wsgi and fcgi.  You obviously need Python, and whatever libraries your app depends upon.  Likely need a database and the appropriate connectors as well, but that should all be in the documentation of whatever project you're trying to host (or framework you're using to write with).

Short answer: almost.